# Axios get parsing boolean value to String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get everything from JSON with Axios get, all works except boolean value, is not parsing to String (Im adding the current state.toString() but not working. Or is there other way to show it ? in backend api "isInstructed":true,

```
        const { id } = this.props.match.params
        axios.get(`/visitors/${id}`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ visitors: res.data });   
        }
```

The render

```
        
        return (
                 <h4>Is instructed? </h4>{this.state.visitors.isInstructed.toString()}
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Are you sure `this.state.visitors.isInstructed` is what you expect? Could you console log `typeof this.state.visitors.isInstructed` and paste it here?

Comment: can you add value for `this.state.visitors` before and after axios call?

Comment: What's isn't working? Do you get an error?

Comment: Console.log =  Cannot read property 'visitors' of undefined. However in return I've got other keys like name, etc BUT not boolean (i.e.this.state.visitors.name) . those don't give this error

Comment: edbefore the line "this.setState({ visitors: res.data });", could you add a console.log(res.data)? And then update us with the returned value?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show data as text, not as an image of text.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the initial value for `this.state.visitors` is `undefined` or `null`.

Try

```
return (
  <h4>Is instructed? </h4>
  {
   this.state.visitors && typeof this.state.visitors.isInstructed !== undefined ?
   this.state.visitors.isInstructed.toString() : 
   null
  }
```

Comment: Yes! It works, just {this.state.visitors.isInstructed && etc..} to be perfect!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your then callback's call, right in the body, try to console.log your res to see what you can retrieve or if it gets some call's errors